# Is $X/R$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

Considere the $X=\mathbb R\times (0, +\infty)$ endowed with the induced topology of $\mathbb R^2$. In $X$ define the equivalence relation:

$$(x_1, y_1)R(x_2, y_2)\iff x_1=x_2.$$

Is it true that the quotient $X/R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

I think so because if we define $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ setting $f(x, y)=x$ then

$$(x_1, y_1)R(x_2, y_2)\implies f(x_1, y_1)=x_1=x_2=f(x_2, y_2)$$

so $f$ descends to the quotient $\widehat{f}: X/R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$\widehat{f}([x, y])=x.$$

This map $f$ is continuous because if $\mathcal{U}$ is open in $\mathbb R$ then

$$f^{-1}(\mathcal{U})=\mathcal{U}\times (0, +\infty)$$ is open in $X$. This implies $\widehat{f}$ is continuous. Clearly $\widehat{f}$ is a bijection, but I can't finish the argument to show it is an homeomorphism.

Thanks.

Comment: can you reduce to showing that if $U\times (0,\infty)$ is open then $U$ is open?

Comment: I'll try. But, is it true that those spaces are indeed homeomorphic?

Comment: @dessind'enfantterrible do you want me to show that $f$ is an open mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but to see the openness, we need to identify what the open sets of $X/R$ are: It consists of precisely all the sets $U\subseteq X/R$ such that the preimage of the projection onto the equivalence classes $X\to X/R$ is open.

The preimages are given precisely by sets $S\subseteq X$ which are closed under this equivalence relation, that is, if $s\in S$, then every $s'$ with $sRs'$ must be  in S as well. In other words, it has to be the union of (even partitioned by) equivalence classes.  In this case, equivalence classes are of the form $\{x\}\times (0,\infty)$. Therefore, S must be of the form $\mathcal S\times (0,\infty)$.

By the definition of the product topology, this is open in $X$ if and only if $\mathcal S\subseteq \mathbb R$ is open.

Thus, the map $\hat f\colon X/R\to \mathbb R$ taking $[(x,y)]=\{x\}\times (0,\infty)$ to $x$ maps an open set $\mathcal U\times (0,\infty)$ to the open set $\mathcal U$, and you're done.